# How to change background image on body element dynamically using angular js(1.3.20)

Tags: angularjs, ng-style

I want to change background image on body element using angular js dynamically.
I am trying to do this as mentioned below:

```
<body ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{vm.img}})'}">
```

Where vm.img is set from the controller, but I am not able to change the image accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you can add style in your body element

```
<body style = "background-image:'url({{backgroundImage}})';background-size: cover;"></body>
```

Comment: That doesn't work either, I am not getting the value from the interpolation, as there is no controller associated to it. Is there any other way to set my background image dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

It's a kind of hacky solution. I used resolve in ui-router which resolved the data before controller gets loaded, added the img to the rootScope and modified the code below and voila!!

```
<body ng-style="{'background-image':'url(' + img +')'}">
```